# can't get github's webhook URL to work on my server

Tags: git, github, centos

My workflow is quite simple:

1. local:

`mkdir testrepo && git init && git add . && git commit -m 'commit X' && git push -u origin master`

All good, my repo from github gets updated.

1. dev server:

`git clone github_repo_url`

I have set up a post receive hook as explained [here](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks).

When I push changes from local, the repo gets updated but my script on the server side with `<?php git pull` doesn't work. If I ssh the server and execute it with `php github.php`, the script does indeed do a `git pull` and the files on the server are getting updated.

I've also tried `<?php $output = shell_exec('git pull'); echo $output;` but the same thing. I push, the repo gets updated, the dev server doesn't do a pull even if the post-receive hook is set up correctly (I can see that with RequestBin).

github.php - 755 permissions. The owner is not root though, if I do a `chown username:group github.php` I get a 500 error.

If/when I run the script, it doesn't ask for password, there's no dialog that could stop the script.. I simply don't get it.

on `git pull` manually logged as root, while on ssh in that directory:

```
git pull
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 3 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From github.com:test/testrepo
   0e678d9..88b3237  master     -> origin/master
Updating 0e678d9..88b3237
Fast-forward
 test.html |    2 +-
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
root@echo [/home/username/public_html/dev/testrepo]#
```

And job done. My files are updated.

**Any ideas please?**

Could it be that apache can't run php scripts by itself? Also, if I ssh into the server but not with the root, and I try to run the php script, I get a Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Answer (score 4):

Another thing you might try is to put your username and password through https like so

> https://username:password@github.com/user/reponame.git

This way you don't have to actually SSH in. This is when you are pulling from your remote repo server. When you add a remote make sure to add those parameters .

Otherwise create an ssh key on your server and link it up with GitHub as a Deploy Key. Make sure that when you create your ssh key that you don't put a password. Otherwise you'll have the same issue that you are having now with it not getting past the authentication phase.

Answer (score 3):

It´s because when you dont do the 'git pull' a password have to be entered. When you are logged in (ssh) i think you are granted access without password. See this link: http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/(gs):GitHub

And this link to guide: http://seancoates.com/blogs/deploy-on-push-from-github